# Execute a function after closing a window (not a child window)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have in my application a button which after being clicked opens up another window (which is a separate python file).

I want to execute a function after this second window has been closed. Is there a way I can capture that window's 'closed' signal or something like that?

Here is my code: (the main window)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
import second_dialog  # the second window I am importing

from sys import exit as sysExit

class Marker(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.openbtn = QPushButton('open')
        self.openbtn.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 150, 31))
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.label_1.setText("HEy")

        HBox = QHBoxLayout()
        HBox.addWidget(self.openbtn)
        HBox.addWidget(self.label_1)
        HBox.addStretch(1)

        VBox = QVBoxLayout()
        VBox.addLayout(HBox)
        VBox.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(VBox)
      
    def open_dialog(self):
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.box = second_dialog.Marker()
        self.box.show()
        

    def do_something(self):
        self.label_1.setText("Closed")
    
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(128, 128, 128, 128))
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEventThred = QApplication([])

    MainApp = Marker()
    MainApp.show()

    MainEventThred.exec()
```

Here is the code for the second window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
import first_window

from sys import exit as sysExit

class Marker(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.openbtn = QPushButton('close')
        self.openbtn.clicked.connect(self.Close)

        HBox = QHBoxLayout()
        HBox.addWidget(self.openbtn)
        HBox.addStretch(1)

        VBox = QVBoxLayout()
        VBox.addLayout(HBox)
        VBox.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(VBox)
      
    def Close(self):
        TEST_draggable.Marker.do_something(first_window.Marker)
        self.close()
        

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(128, 128, 128, 128))
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEventThred = QApplication([])

    MainApp = Marker()
    MainApp.show()

    MainEventThred.exec()
```

The code does not run and throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some/path/second_dialog.py", line 28, in Close
    TEST_draggable.Marker.do_something(first_window.Marker)
  File "some/path/first_window.py", line 39, in do_something
    self.label_1.setText("clicked")
AttributeError: type object 'Marker' has no attribute 'label_1'
[1]    7552 abort (core dumped)  /usr/local/bin/python3
```

How can I fix this? I've looked up a lot of forums suspecting circular imports as the culprit but I'm not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with imports, but with the fact that you're trying to run an *instance* method on a *class*.

The "culprit" is here:

```
TEST_draggable.Marker.do_something(first_window.Marker)
```

`first_window.Marker` will be used for the `self` argument in `do_something`, but since it is the class, it has no `label_1` attribute (only the instances of that class have that attribute). I suggest you to do some research on how classes and instances work in general, and how to deal with them in Python.

The easiest solution is to create your own signal for the second window and connect that signal on the function that will "do_something". Instead of connecting to a new function, then, we subclass the [`closeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) and send the signal from there, so that we can capture the close even when the user clicks the dedicated button on the title bar. Note that if you want to change the behavior of `close` you can just *override* it and then call the base implementation (`super().close()`) instead of using another function name (which should not have a capitalized name, by the way, as they should only be used for classes and constants).

This is the *second* class; be aware that using identical names for different classes is a very bad idea.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class Marker(QWidget):
    closed = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.openbtn = QPushButton('close')
        self.openbtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        # ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closed.emit()
```

Then, in the first:

```
class Marker(QWidget):
    # ...
    def open_dialog(self):
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.box = second_dialog.Marker()
        self.box.closed.connect(self.do_something)
        self.box.show()
```